# Quiescent current of 12v brushless water pump

Tags: fluid-pump

I couldn't find the datasheet to my Quioran QR50E water pump and I want to estimate if I can run an arduino and 4 of those on a battery for longer than a month.
I don't know the quiescent current of the pump and I think it could be much more than the arduino's.
It is a 12V DC, 5W water pump with a Qmax of 280 liters per hour.

What is it's quiescent current?
If no one knows, could I astimate it?
What are normal values for such small pumps?

Comment: Quiescent current for something like a pump would typically be 0.00A, because it's switched off and not running. Are you sure you have your terminology correct and it's really the *quiescent* current you're looking for? > qui·es·cent : adjective : in a state or period of inactivity or dormancy <

Comment: Use a relay, don't power it directly from the Arduino. How big is your battery?

Comment: I can choose the battery, that was the whole idea of the question to plan ahead. I like the idea of relay and I use a module that has quiescent current of about 2ma so it's an order of magnitude lower than the arduino so I'm set. Tnx a lot!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The pump itself requires nothing when it is not running. The brushless controller may well draw significant current. There is not a "normal" or "typical" value here, it's whatever the designer chose. For example they may have saved a few pennies by using a regulator that draws 5 or 10mA with no load, which may seem perfectly reasonable if battery power is not being considered. 10mA at 12V for a month is equivalent to 5W for more than 17 hours.

Easiest thing is to measure it. But if it draws too much you can likely simply cut power to it when it is not being used, with a relay or a MOSFET.